# Need to center continuous variables in GAMs?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, centering

This is just a quick question, but I remember reading somewhere that continuous variables used in splines for generalized additive models ought to be centered (*especially* for GAMs rather than just as a general rule of thumb for models).

However, I now can't find that advice anywhere and wonder if I perhaps read something wrong.

**Is it really best practice to center all continuous variables used in GAMs or GAMMs?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no requirement to centre variables with GAMs. The basis expansion applied to a variable (or variables in the case of tensor product smooths) is subjected to identifiability constraints, which typically centre the smooth about 0 via a sum to zero constraint, but this happens whether you centre the variable or not.

Comment: Just a quick question - sorry if I should create a separate post? I get significantly improved prediction accuracy when I centre/scale my continuous predictors before using bam() for logistic regression. What is the explanation for this, if centring is done automatically? Is it the scaling? Thanks

Comment: You might see improvements due to centring, especially if your variables have large values and don't vary too much around the mean (centring will subtract off then a large mean value from each observation, leaving numerically smaller deviations about this mean), but you could achieve this yourself by rescaling the variables in some way (dividing by some large value, but not too large that you make the values tiny). Scaling to unit variance will weight all variables equally while centring them so  that may help numerically if you have large values and large variances

Comment: I should add that {mgcv} isn't centring the variables, it's centring the basis expansion through the imposition of the identifiability constraints. I miss-spoke in my original answer about the thing with the intercept; this thing about being the estimated value of y when all covariates are 0 doesn't really apply in the GAM, where the intercept is just the average over the data (or for a reference group if parametric factor terms are involved).

Comment: So the issue of whether centring and scaling to unit variance helps or not is really one of numerical stability - it shouldn't change the model fit but it might  if the model fit was unstable before due to numerically large values being involved in the computations used during fitting.

Comment: Many thanks for the response. That makes sense - the predictors I'm centring/scaling are annual incomes so have very large values (but do vary around the mean a lot too).